# Promote PyQt Widget

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm using PyQt and trying to promote a widget in QtDesigner. I'm able to get it working if I specify the full module path, in the "Header file" field, to the file that contains my widget sub-class.

Is there a better way to promote a widget in QtDesigner to a PyQt widget without having to specify the full module path?

Here's an example to hopefully illustrate what I'm talking about:

/PythonModuleRoot/Ui/MainUi.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
class MainUi(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'MainUi.ui'), self)
```

/PythonModuleRoot/Ui/CustomWidget.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
class CustomWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
```

/PythonModuleRoot/Ui/MainUi.ui

In MainUi.ui I promote a widget and set the Header file field to: "PythonModuleRoot.Ui.CustomWidget".

Comment: You have answered your own question in an edit. Why not post your solution as an answer instead? [Posting self-answers is encouraged here.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get it. It would be very helpful if you could include the XML for MainUi.ui for the simple example above, perhaps before and after promoting it to Promoted class name: CustomWidgets.py, Header file:  Widgets.CustomWidget.py, I guess,... to see if I can understand the whole process.

Comment: @keegan3d : You could have posted the screenshot of `Promote to` UI !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it figured out, my actual code is slightly different then the simplified example I gave. My actual code is more like this:

```
/PythonModuleRoot/Ui/MainUi.py

/PythonModuleRoot/Ui/MainUi.ui

/PythonModuleRoot/Ui/Widgets/CustomWidget.py
```

So I just needed to change the contents of Header file to be how MainUi would import CustomWidget, so: "Widgets.CustomWidget". This article pointed me in the right direction: http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg17893.html