# How do I use promote to in Qt Designer in pyqt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, designer

In the designer when I right click a widget, and I click promote to I get this window. See the screenshot below.

I have never used this feature. Basically, the header file is confusing me. What is it for? Does that mean I can create a new class in this case, inheriting QLineEdit and add more methods to it? What is the promoted class name?

[image: Promote widget]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Promote PyQt Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832695/promote-pyqt-widget)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This allows you to use custom widgets defined elsewhere, which designer otherwise wouldn't know about.

For example, if you've defined a widget `MyLabel` derived from `QLabel`, then you can define it here and then just insert a `QLabel` as placeholder in your ui and promote it to `MyLabel`.

The uic compiler will then include the necessary imports/includes, for example if you specified `mypackage/mycomponent.h` as header file and `MyLabel` as class name, then `pyuic` will add

```
from mypackage.mycomponent import MyLabel
```

(note how the `.h` is ignored, and slashes are converted to `.` by pyuic to keep compatibility with python)

*Global include* is ignored by pyuic, it only affects `uic` (generate `#include "mypackage/mycomponent.h"` or `#include <mypackage/mycomponent.h>` for c++)

Comment: **This is inscrutable black magic.** The Qt (Creater|Designer) UX *really* needs to explicitly acknowledge the existence of other languages other than C++. The need to specify a C++ header file, whose filetype `pyuic` and `pysideuic` then silently ignore, is particularly unforgivable.