# Overriding QGraphicsView paintEvent function in Qt Designer

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qt-designer

Im writing some simple python application using PyQt and QtDesigner. I've designed mainView in designer which has a QGraphicsView and some buttons inside. My question is, how should I draw shapes on that QGraphicsView?

Without QtDesigner, I would have created class extending QGraphicsView and overriden its paintEvent() method. However, Designer generates single Ui_MainWindow class, so I can't set it's QGraphicsView field to my specific subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to promote the `QGraphicsView` to your own class that subclasses `QGraphicsView`. To learn how to promote widgtes in Qt Designer, see this SO post: [How do I use promote to in Qt Designer in pyqt4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622014/how-to-use-promote-to-in-qt-designer-in-pyqt4)

In your subclass, you can override the `paintEvent` method is usual.